# How to resubmit dask jobs (from previous dead workers) when new workers are added after old workers have died?

Tags: dask, dask-delayed

Is there a way in dask to resubmit jobs (from previous dead workers) when new workers are added after old workers have died?

Might it be possible to achieve this using a scheduler plugin `distributed.diagnostics.plugin.SchedulerPlugin`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `future` API, then you can examine the status property of the individual `future` objects using `.status` and take actions accordingly. For example, if `f` is a future object then we can ask the scheduler to retry its calculation based on some condition like this:

```py
if f.status.isin(['error', 'cancelled', 'lost']):
   f.retry()
```